# jQuery not work in form

Tags: jquery

When I submit form, Everything is ok like data insert into database. But the page is blank and showing data insert success. The query doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#userName').val();
    var email = $('#eMail').val();
    var fullname = $('#fullName');
    var country = $('#country');
    var sponsorid = $('#sponsorId');

    $.ajax({
      url: "register_submit.php",
      method = 'POST',
      data: {
        username = username,
        email = email,
        fullname = fullname,
        country = country,
        sponsorid = sponsorid
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $("#success").html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Where is the problem? what Can I do?

Comment: $('#fullName') **.val()** etc ...

Comment: `method='POST',` wut,

Comment: This can't be the actual code, if the data is getting inserted into the DB. You have a syntax error that should prevent it from executing.

Comment: Object syntax is `{ key: value, key: value, ...}` not `{ key = value, key = value, ... }`

Comment: @Barmar well, unless the syntax error is bad enough to allow the form to submit via postback :p

Answer (score -1):

It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve, what is the goal?

In your case, it seem like the "result" variable should be HTML string that is returned from the server and you want to display that HTML.

So check if result is valid HTML and is what you expect.

Also check that you have a `<div id="success"> </div>` as this is where jQuery will inject the HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [why do I need 50 reputation to comment, what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I will not help anymore, until I make 50rep.